# Read Path and draw circles

Tags: svg

i am working on SVG, problem i am facing is that i want to read the path and after reading it i want to draw the circles through   tag used in svg, on that path, kindly help me out any help will be awesome...Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Your question appears to be lacking information. You want to draw circles on a path...where? How big are the circles and where are they located? At every control point with random sizes? Evenly spaced along the path, a fixed size, and abutting?

Comment: i have a path of a String, now i want to read that path and want to draw the dynamic circles rendered on tht path string, how it will be implemeted, any Idea..?

Answer (score 0):

*The information you have provided still does not make sense to me. Here's a guess at what you might be looking for.*

If you have a `<path>` element and you want to place circles along the path, you can use the [`getPointAtLength()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) method to find the location at an arbitrary distance along the path.

Then you can create `<circle>` elements (or `<use>` elements that reference a circle) and place them at this location.

Here is a demo that uses this technique (and also happens to create a `<polygon>` of the result):
http://phrogz.net/svg/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml